# Conservar imagen, cuando se edita un formulario?

Tags: php, html5

Hola buenas tardes a todos, quizas sea un problema muy sencillo pero la verdad tengo días atorado, el detalle es que tengo un formulario de usuario que es capaz de subir imagen y lo guarda en la base de datos todo bien, el problema es que cuando edito al usuario y le doy guardar me quita la imagen, luego utilice la consola de firefox y me di cuenta que aunque en el input file, el valor que le pongo es el de la base de datos, a la hora de hacer el envio no envia el valor y sigue borrando, por favor ayudenme lo necesito gracias a todos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te dice @javiertapia, la solución es más sencilla. Cuando, por ejemplo, un usuario edita su perfil y este incluye su avatar; por defecto se muestra esta en un apartado de preferencia encodeada en base64:

```
$id = $_SESSION["user"]["id"];

// consulta

$data = array();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$entry = array(
  "name" => $row["name"],
  "lastname" => $row["lastname"],
  "email" => $row["email"],
  "avatar" => base64_encode($row["avatar"])
);

array.push($data, $entry);

echo json_encode($data);
```

En el código de arriba se ha convertido la información del usuario a un arreglo. La imagen se ha encodeado desde un blob a base64 por medio de [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) y se ha enviado esta información por JSON (puede ser como array y enviaro a la vista para iterarse en esta).

Luego, en el cliente obtendrías este JSON:

> **Nota:** en este ejemplo uso la nueva API para AJAX [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). Puedes usar `jQuery#ajax` o el clásico [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). Si usas este método asegúrate de incluir el [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) en tu HTML.

```
fetch('/profile')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(user => {
    updateEditForm(user);
  });

function updateEditForm (user) {
  let form = document.getElementById('user-edit-form');
  form.name.value = user.name;
  form.lastname.value = user.lastname;
  form.username.value = user.username;
  form.email.value = user.email;

  setPhoto(user.avatar);
}

function setPhoto (imgdata) {
  let img = document.getElementById('avatar');
  img.src = imagedata;
}
```

Ahora, ¿cómo saber si se ha cambiado la foto? Simple, creando un objeto [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) y verificando si la llave `avatar` tiene un valor válido. Si no lo tiene, se elimina esa entrada del objeto.

```
function updateUser (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = document.getElementById('user-edit-form');
  let newData = new FormData(form);

  // elimina la entrada 'avatar' si no se ha escodigo un archivo
  if (!newData.get('avatar')) {
    newData.delete('avatar');
  }

  fetch('/profile', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: newData
  })
  .then(() => {
    alert('Perfil actualizado');
  });
}
```

En PHP, solo debes proceder a realizar el update con la data que has recibido.

Answer (score 2):

No coloques el valor de la imagen en el `input file`. Mejor, cuando hayas enviado el formulario, verifica el `input file`. Si está vacío, no hagas nada. Pero tiene datos (lo que significa que el usuario seleccionó una imagen) la subes al servidor y reemplazas lo que corresponda en la base de datos.

Comment: Pero por ejemplo hay tres casos
1.- Que el no modifique la imagen y que se conserve esa imagen
2.- Que quite la imagen y que la imagen se quede en blanco
3.- Que modifique la imagen y se quede la imagen que se modifco

Y siempre me manda el input vacio, en el caso 1 y en el caso 2, en el 3 no tengo problemas

Comment: 1. El usuario no modifica la imagen y envía el form. Tú validas que el `input:file` está vacío y no haces nada (la imagen existente se mantiene).  2. Sugiero agregar un `checkbox` con la etiqueta "Eliminar imagen". Al enviar el formulario tú verificas que se envió el valor del checkbox y si es así eliminas la imagen.

Comment: Gracias ya me diste una idea si la realizo te la hago saber

Comment: Listo @javiertapia lo hice como tu lo hiciste pero en este caso haciendo comparaciones con la imagen anterior y con javascript y funciono muy bien

Answer (score 0):

lo mas recomendable es que si solo vas a modificar informacion del usuario mas no todo el contenido, ponerlo en otro formulario que no sea donde ingresas el usuario al inicio que es donde le asignas una imagen, o si lo quieres hacer la actualizacion en el mismo formulario te recomiendo que manejes condicionales en los campos.

```
<?php
//valor que se envia para relizar la consulta y modificar los datos
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$id = $_GET['id'];
//consulta
$slq =$conexion->query("select * from tabla where id='$id'");

}
?>
<label>usario</label>
<input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($id)){ echo $nombre; } ?>" />
```

en el caso del campo de la imagen puedes ocultarlo para que no aparesca o puesdes ponerlo con la ruta que actualmente tienes en la base de datos, al realizar el `update`no la subes al servidor para que no tengas informacion repetida y en la tabla la podrias sobreescribir la ruta que seria la misma.